# How to load one cell inside another cell's view.?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

[image: Its my inner cell]

The above one is my inner cell. I want to load this cell inside the below cell. The number of inner cell is dynamic.
[image]

The above one is my main cell. The red colored section is a UIView. I want to add numbers of innerCell dynamically into the UIView. I tried the below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlightCellMain", for: indexPath) as? FlightCellMain
    let innerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlightCell", for: indexPath) as? FlightCell


    mainCell?.flightCellView.addSubview(innerCell!)
    mainCell?.backgroundColor = .clear
    innerCell?.backgroundColor = .clear
   // innerCell?.innerCellWidthConst.constant = (mainCell?.mainView.frame.width)!
    self.showStopsView(2, self.airportlist, (innerCell?.leftRound)!, (innerCell?.rightRound)!, (innerCell?.centerLine)!, (innerCell?.routeView)!)
    mainCell?.flightCellViewHieghtConst.constant = (mainCell?.flightCellViewHieghtConst.constant)! + 125
    innerCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
    mainCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
    return mainCell!
}
```

[image]

But the result is getting like this. I provided autolayout. When I run the two cells individually it fits its content.. Whats wrong am I doing ?

[image]

The above picture is the model that I'm trying to achieve.  Where the number of flights details is dynamic.

Comment: For inner Table View cell you need to add tableView in Cell View and load the tableView cell into them. And inner tableView view must be have fix height.

Comment: @Aman19ish Please have a look at the edited question. I added the result screen that I'm expecting.

Comment: OK. But for this UI why you using the inner cell . and If you need the code for tableVIew inner cell then send me your mail id.

Comment: Its not getting the result like this..

Comment: I think, i am not getting your question. But according to me for Inner tableView cell not use automatic dimensions .(Its not working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create a FlightDisplayView(UIView).

```
import UIKit

class FlightDisplayView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit (){

       let xibs = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FlightDisplayView", owner: self, options: nil)
       let view = xibs?.first as! UIView
       view.frame = self.bounds;
       self.addSubview(view)

    }

}
```

[image: FlightDisplayView]

**Step 2:** Create a FlightDisplayCell(UITableViewCell).

```
import UIKit

class FlightViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var innerCellView:FlightDisplayView!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

   }

   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

}
```

**Step 3:** Create a mainCell(UITableViewCell).

```
import UIKit

class mainCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var heightConstraintForFlightTableView : NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       table.delegate = self
       table.dataSource = self
       table.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
       table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       table.register(UINib.init(nibName: "FlightViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "FlightViewCell")

       heightConstraintForFlightTableView.constant = 0.0
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

   func setInformation(_ numberOFFlight : CGFloat, _ information : NSDictionary) {
        heightConstraintForFlightTableView.constant = numberOFFlight * 155.0

    // 155 is fixed flight cell height
       table.reloadData()
   }

}


extension mainCell:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 3
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlightViewCell")
       return cell!
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }

}
```

[image: mainCell]

**Step 4:** Use mainCell into your controller. (3 cell information added as a inner cell)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell") as? mainCell

    let information:NSDictionary = [:]
    cell?.setInformation(3, information)
    return cell!
}
```

[image: Complete View]